# Creating Tabels Using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm reading **Beginner ASP.NET MVC 4** and I have to create some tables using T-SQL. All works fine so far, but when I'm trying to copy this in T-SQL editor (in Visual Studio 2012)

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile] 
ADD
[FirstName] VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
[LastName] VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
[Email] VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL;
```

The error is :

> *In this context, you must specify columns by using a CREATE TABLE instead of by using ALTER TABLE statement*

In other table I have following code:

```
...
REFERENCES **[UserProfile]** ([UserId])
...
```

but in book is no [UserProfile] table.
Can somebody help me with this `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: Where are you getting that error message from?  I know of no such error message in SQL Server...?

Answer (score 1):

`ALTER TABLE` will work only if that table exists in the database.

If you say there is no **UserProfile** table, then you should create it with:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile] (
  [FirstName] VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  [LastName] VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  [Email] VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Ok but as I said, in other table is <code> REFERENCES [UserProfile] ([UserId])</code> which means that UserProfile table contains a column call UserId and the book doesn't say that...

Comment: You can add the **UserId** column your self. There is no "Secret thing" here. My guest is that this book has a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The [UserId] column should be created before ALTER TABLE. And here the Alter Table is just add the column [FirstName],[LastName] and [Email].

Answer (score 0):

First check if the table exists, if not create.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.UserProfile', N'U'))
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile] (
          [FirstName] VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
          [LastName] VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
          [Email] VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL
        )
END
```

Then check if each individual columns that you need exist and take care of those

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = 'FirstName' AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.UserProfile', N'U'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE dbo.UserProfile 
        ADD [FirstName] VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = 'LastName' AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.UserProfile', N'U'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE dbo.UserProfile 
        ADD LastName VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = 'Email' AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.UserProfile', N'U'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE dbo.UserProfile 
        ADD Email VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL
END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see this in Visual Studio, make sure your script file is not included in Build, right click on .sql file and see properties, set 'Build Action' to none. That will get rid of the error. This error broke the build in Jenkins and this solution fixed that for me.